# How to avoid 'undefind' adding following typescript string?

Tags: typescript

I take some model values and return them in my .ts file to HTML. In HTML I will bind it using {} expression.but some situation, data is not available then came it as undefined. In such situation undefined also added to the return string. need some expert help to resolve this.

```
getInformation(): string {
    const i1  = this.A.x1;
    const n = this.A.x2;
    const c = this.A.x3;
    return `${String(c)} ${n} ${ii?.d1} ${i1?.d2}, `;
  }
```

In the above code  `${ii?.d1} ${i1?.d2}` can be undefined and I need to avoid it added to sting that condition.

---

Now some cases text came as `A B Undifind Undefind` such kind of cases need to correct as `'A B'`

Comment: So what *exactly* would you want to return in such a case?

Comment: I need to return 'other text ' with out appending undefind .(undifind should not append to text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make an array with the values and filter the undefined and join them.

```
return [String(c), n, ii?.d1, i1?.d2].filter(i => i).join(' ')
```

Comment: Thank you it is working, but need to add ',  ' , comma with space to end of the text , can you help me?